# Live Agent: Users current location (URL)

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud

Is it possible to get the users current location (URL) they have started the chat from. To see where the user currently is. I am unable to find an example of this.

We make use of Embedded Service

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_overview.htm

The javascript is loaded on every page.

The goal is to see where the customer is on the website at all times.

The code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://service.force.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var initESW = function(gslbBaseURL) {
        embedded_svc.settings.displayHelpButton = true; //Or false
        embedded_svc.settings.language = 'nl'; //For example, enter 'en' or 'en-US'
        embedded_svc.settings.offlineSupportMinimizedText = 'Chat met een expert';
        embedded_svc.settings.defaultMinimizedText = 'Chat met een expert'; //(Defaults to Chat with an Expert)
        //embedded_svc.settings.disabledMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Agent Offline)

        embedded_svc.settings.loadingText = 'laden...'; //(Defaults to Loading)
        //embedded_svc.settings.storageDomain = 'yourdomain.com'; //(Sets the domain for your deployment so that visitors can navigate subdomains during a chat session)

        // Settings for Chat
        //embedded_svc.settings.directToButtonRouting = function(prechatFormData) {
            // Dynamically changes the button ID based on what the visitor enters in the pre-chat form.
            // Returns a valid button ID.
        //};
        var accountData = document.getElementById('myaccount') && document.getElementById('myaccount').dataset.account;
        if(accountData) {
          var accountDataObject = JSON.parse(accountData);
          embedded_svc.settings.prepopulatedPrechatFields = {
              FirstName: accountDataObject.first_name,
              LastName: accountDataObject.last_name,
              Email: accountDataObject.email
          };
        }

      embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
        "label": "URL",
        "value":  window.location.href,
        "displayToAgent": true
      }];

        //embedded_svc.settings.fallbackRouting = []; //An array of button IDs, user IDs, or userId_buttonId
        //embedded_svc.settings.offlineSupportMinimizedText = '...'; //(Defaults to Contact Us)

        embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
        embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';

        embedded_svc.init(
            'https://xxx.my.salesforce.com',
            'https://xxx.secure.force.com/liveAgentSetupFlow',
            gslbBaseURL,
            '',
            'Chat_Team',
            {
                baseLiveAgentContentURL: 'https://c.la1-c2-fra.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
                deploymentId: '',
                buttonId: '',
                baseLiveAgentURL: 'https://d.la1-c2-fra.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
                eswLiveAgentDevName: 'Chat_Team',
                isOfflineSupportEnabled: true
            }
        );
    };

    if (!window.embedded_svc) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', 'https://xxx.my.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js');
        s.onload = function() {
            initESW(null);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(s);
    } else {
        initESW('https://service.force.com');
    }
</script>
```

In this code I tried:

```
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
        "label": "URL",
        "value":  window.location.href,
        "displayToAgent": true
      }];
```

But this does not work as expected. At the end of the chat I would still like to have a history of all the pages visited during the chat and possibly a timestamp.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hi Thomas. Welcome to SF.SE. Presumably they're coming from the URL of your chat applet. Are you asking about the IP address from which the user's browser originates it's connection to the internet and ultimately reaches your site?

Comment: No, I mean the URL they are currently at. E.g if they are on a category page I would like to see the URL in the case like http://mysite.com/a-category

Comment: How the LiveAgent JS code is added to your website? Is it added in each and every page?

Comment: It always comes in a field "Referring Site" in LiveChatTranscript Object. If you wanna ask something then provide more detail.

Comment: In the referring site is only the main domain, not the page they are on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to update an attribute URL using the following code:

```
  embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
    "label": "URL",
    "value":  window.location.href,
    "displayToAgent": true,
    "transcriptFields": ["URL__c"]
  }];
```

Though this does not update dynamically when the user changes pages.